# How to load a Git clone into QtCreator

Tags: c++, git, qt-creator

I'm very new to using any sort of version control with QtCreator, so I'm sure I'm just making a rookie mistake, but here goes:

I am able to create a clone of a repository (https://github.com/dsacre/klick.git). All of the files are there. The problem lies with getting this clone into QtCreator for me to mess around with.

I go about making a clone through **File -> New File or Project -> Import Project -> Git Clone**

I enter **https://github.com/dsacre/klick.git** on the "Repository" line and then hit **Next**.

The following text is then displayed:

```
Cloning into 'klick'...
remote: Counting objects: 1223, done.        
remote: Total 1223 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1223        
Receiving objects: 100% (1223/1223), 407.30 KiB | 29.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (923/923), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Succeeded.
```

Then, when I click **Finish**, a dialog box appears, saying "Failed to open project in /home/tylrrc/klick" and "No file to open found in /home/tylrrc/klick". When I look in /home/tylrrc, I can see /klick and all of the files it contains.

What am I doing wrong here?

Does QtCreator require a special type of file to be present in a project before it can open it?

Comment: I think you are talking about the IDE QtCreator not the c++ framework Qt.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Vladimir's answer, there is a built-in automatic way to do this.

You can import the project.

1. Click **File**->**New File or Project ...**. This will open the following dialog. Select the option **Import Project**->**Import Existing Project**, as shown below.

[image]

2. Next give the name and path (*/home/tylrrc/klick* in your case) for your project.

[image]

3. You can select if you would like particular file extensions to be included or excluded from the view/project. If you are not sure, (and probably for most simple projects), it is enough to just go ahead with the defaults suggested by QtCreator.

[image]

4. Finally include (or not) your Qt project files to the Git repo.

[image]

Depending on how simple your project structure is, you **may** be able to build your project now from within QtCreator.

**EDIT:**

I noted that the build-system used in the [project](https://github.com/dsacre/klick.git) is scons. As per the documentation on [this page](https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/IDEIntegration#markdown-header-qt-creator), the above import steps should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Does QT require a special type of file to be present in a project
>   before it can open it?

Yes, any Qt project must has a ***.pro** file: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html

Therefore you need to create new empty project in QtCreator:
`File -> New File or Project -> Application -> Qt Widgets/Console Application`. Then you should add the files which you have downloaded:

[image]